# MariaDB syntax support weird

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have several MariaDB instances e.g. 10.1.17, 10.1.25 and 10.2.6

I made a SQL that runs on 10.2.6 and 10.1.17, but not on 10.1.25 and I don't know why.

```
ALTER TABLE FOOBAR ALTER CREATED SET DEFAULT NOW();
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOW()'

What works on 10.1.25 is `CREATE TABLE` but only there and only `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead to `NOW()`.

```
CREATE TABLE `FOOBAR` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CREATED` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I also tried but that also not work.

```
ALTER TABLE FOOBAR ALTER CREATED SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Perhaps they want the developers to use ANSI SQL's current_timestamp instead of that proprietary now().

Comment: Weird, according to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/alter-table-statement/), it should work. Maybe try to change it to `CURRENT_TIME` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` and `CURRENT_TIME` also doesn't work with `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: In 10.1.25 in table `FOOBAR` what type is column `CREATED`? `datetime`?

Comment: Yes it's from type `datetime` to avoid the year 2038 problem of `timestamp`

Comment: And every time you get the same error or it's different? According to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/#default) it should works from 10.0.1, so there shouldn't be problem.

Comment: 2038 is 21 years from now.  Do you know of any 21-year-old computers still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.25-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FOOBAR`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE `FOOBAR` (
    ->   `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `CREATED_0` DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
    ->   `CREATED_1` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->   `CREATED_2` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    ->   `CREATED_3` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->   `CREATED_4` DATETIME,
    ->   `CREATED_5` DATETIME,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SHOW CREATE TABLE `FOOBAR`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: FOOBAR
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `FOOBAR` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CREATED_0` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CREATED_1` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CREATED_2` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CREATED_3` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CREATED_4` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_5` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> [CREATE TABLE :: DEFAULT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/#default)
>
> ...
>
> Before MariaDB 10.2.1 you couldn't usually provide an expression or
>   function to evaluate at insertion time. You had to provide a constant
>   default value instead. The one exception is that you may use
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value for a TIMESTAMP column to use
>   the current timestamp at insertion time.
>
> ...
>
> **MariaDB starting with [10.0.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1001-release-notes/)**
>
> `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` may also be used as the default value for a `DATETIME`

However, the following statements fail:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> ALTER TABLE `FOOBAR`
    ->   ALTER COLUMN `CREATED_4` SET DEFAULT NOW();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
                    that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
                    right syntax to use near 'NOW()' at line 2

MariaDB [_]> ALTER TABLE `FOOBAR`
    ->   ALTER COLUMN `CREATED_5` SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
                    that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
                    right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()' at line 2
```

> [ALTER TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/)
>
> ...
>
> **MariaDB starting with [10.2.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1021-release-notes/)**
>
> `DEFAULT` with expressions and `DROP CONSTRAINT` was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1
>
> ...

---

**From MariaDB 10.2.1**

Sentence:

```
MariaDB [_]> ALTER TABLE `FOOBAR`
    -> ALTER COLUMN `CREATED_4` SET DEFAULT NOW(),
    -> ALTER COLUMN `CREATED_5` SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

will work, see [db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f6975cd114e78ce27245221aaa303b72).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `type` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `name`;